Statistical test for count values
I have 4 stories that I have the word count and the count for how many plural words are in each:



Story
Num Words
Plurals




1
356
45


2
273
23


3
303
28


4
289
42



I am wondering if it is possible to do a statistical test to determine if there is a significant difference between these stories in terms of the word count and then another test to determine if there is a significant difference between the stories in terms of the number of plurals.
The purpose of the test is to ensure that these stories are not significantly different in terms of their difficulty of reading. It is for a psychology study where we need to ensure that there is no confound in the story difficulty. There are other more relevant word characteristics that we are testing for but those are continuous values that we can do other tests on.
I don't have a population frequency to compare against in order to use the Fisher Exact test, I don't think I can use a chi-squared test because it seems like the counts there should be related, like testing whether a group of people like apples or oranges or bananas and one person can not choose two options, and I am a little stuck trying to figure out what test I can use here.

Perhaps a test is inappropriate or unnecessary for the conclusions you want to draw. Try writing what you want to say and then ask where a test would enhance the strength of your argument.

(1) A good study design would block on stories to ensure any confounding effect of their varying readability, &c. was averaged out of treatment-effect estimates. (2) If shorter/longer stories, or stories with a lower/higher proportion of plural forms, are supposed to be more or less difficult per se, then it's as @Ben says. (3) If you had a statistical model of how the distribution of story length, or of the proportion of plural forms, should look for stories of equal readability, then perhaps ... - but you don't, & no obvious ones suggest themselves.

(4) There are umpteen measures of readabilty in common use. Assessing the extent to which they agree for your stories would be a more fruitful line of statistical enquiry.

There is no such thing as a "statistically significant" difference for known quantities
Statistical hypothesis tests are used to test hypotheses relating to things that are unknown which are inferred from observed data.  In that context, a "statistically significant" difference refers to a significant amount of evidence of a difference in the underlying unknown quantities of interest that are the subject of inference.
In the present case the number of words in each story is known, and these are different.  There is no uncertainty about this --- the stories have different word counts and numbers of plurals.  Because there is no unknown quantity of interest here, there is no applicable statistical test and no value in trying to assess a "significant difference" in anything.  Whilst there may be some type of "significant" difference in known magnitudes (in a non-statistical sense that we call "practical significance") there is no such thing as a "statistically significant" difference for known quantities.

Yes it is possible to test.  Whether the results are meaningful is another discussion.
Counts can be modeled as coming from a Poisson distribution, so we compare 2 models, in model 1 all 4 counts come from a single Poisson distribution with a common mean, in the other model each count comes from a Poisson distribution, but each with its own mean.  The test is if the simpler model (1 mean) does as well a job of fitting the data as the more complicated model, or if the more complicated model does contribute to the fit.
Here is some R code and results:
> tmpdf <- data.frame(Story=1:4,
+                     NumWords=c(356,273,303,289),
+                     Plurals=c(45,23,28,42))
> fit1 <- glm(NumWords ~ factor(Story), data=tmpdf,
+             family=poisson())
> fit0 <- update(fit1, . ~ 1)
> anova(fit0, fit1, test='Chisq')
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: NumWords ~ 1
Model 2: NumWords ~ factor(Story)
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
1         3     12.437                        
2         0      0.000  3   12.437 0.006027 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> AIC(fit0, fit1)
     df      AIC
fit0  1 44.65508
fit1  4 38.21828
> 
> fit2 <- glm(Plurals ~ factor(Story), data=tmpdf,
+             family=poisson())
> fit0.2 <- update(fit2, . ~ 1)
> anova(fit0.2, fit2, test='Chisq')
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: Plurals ~ 1
Model 2: Plurals ~ factor(Story)
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
1         3     10.095                       
2         0      0.000  3   10.095  0.01777 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> AIC(fit0.2, fit2)
       df      AIC
fit0.2  1 33.47969
fit2    4 29.38441

Since the tests are based on an asymptotic Chi-squared result, it is often a good idea to run some simulations under the null and some alternatives to see how they behave:
> simfun1 <- function(lambda=c(35, 35, 35, 35)) {
+   tmp <- data.frame(Story=factor(seq_along(lambda)), 
+                     y = rpois(length(lambda), lambda)
+                     )
+   fit <- glm(y ~ Story, data=tmp, family=poisson())
+   drop1(fit, test='Chisq')$`Pr(>Chi)`[2]
+ }
> 
> out1 <- replicate(1000, simfun1())
> hist(out1)
> mean(out1 <= 0.05)
[1] 0.053
> 
> out2 <- replicate(1000, simfun1(c(44, 44, 25, 25)))
> hist(out2)
> mean(out2 <= 0.05)
[1] 0.795

So in your case, the models with 4 different means fit better than a model based on a single mean.  But whether that difference is enough to be meaningful is up to you to decide.  Or if the Poisson distribution is reasonable and meaningful.

Thanks so much for your reply! I really appreciate you including the code as well. I'm unsure which answer to accept, I'm curious what you think of the other answer.

At least you could upvote if it helped. Then you decide which worked better.

Not thinking about this for very long, I wonder whether this might actually be equivalent to a chi squared test on plural vs, not plural over the four stories?

@ChristianHennig: No, there are two separate models here: one of the no. words, & one of the no. plurals (without regard to the no.words). The test used is equivalent to the likelihood-ratio goodness-of-fit test of the null hypothesis of equal probabilities for each outcome in a multinomial distribution (condition on the overall total of counts across stories). But model each of the 8 counts on story & plural vs non plural & the GOF test for the additive model is what you're referring to. (Usual variants are the LRT (deviance or G test), & Rao's score test (Pearson's chi-squared test)).


The purpose of the test is to ensure that these stories are not significantly different in terms of their difficulty of reading. It is for a psychology study where we need to ensure that there is no confound in the story difficulty.

I think this is not an issue of statistical significance in a test of equality, but rather of whether a treatment difference that's present is large enough to matter.
The treatments differ. They are not identical. The question is not whether we can distinguish them with a test - assuming we could justify a test, with sufficiently long stories of similar relative lengths to these we would almost certainly reject the null and with shorter stories we generally would not, though the null would certainly be false. Near-certainty of rejection  in long stories does not mean the difference was consequential. Similarly, failure to reject due to lack of power in short stories does not mean the difference was not consequential.
In short, assuming it made sense to apply a test at all, I think you're making a mistake in looking for statistical significance in an equality-null hypothesis test. It would not address the actual issue here.
[If a test could be justified at all, an equivalence test might be reasonable, but I think the central issue is establishing that some measure of equivalence is actually meaningful in context, and might be sufficient to see that the differences were not consequential, or were.]
This issue would be better addressed at the study-design stage by use of a suitable experimental design, not after the fact when it's too late to fix it.
Leaving aside that its the wrong tool for the task at hand in any case, I'll now address the extent to which we can justify probability calculations for such tests.

I am wondering if it is possible to do a statistical test

You're after some form of hypothesis test.
Hypotheses are statements about populations or processes that we can't/don't observe the entirety of. Hypothesis tests (I imagine this is intended to be in the Neyman-Pearson framework) set up a pair of such hypotheses, called the null and alternative. These are typically framed as explicit statements about a parameter or parameters of some process(es) or population(s), which are not treated equally; we look for evidence that the situation under the null - accompanied by some assumptions - is not tenable, in which case we'd seek to reject it in favour of the alternative.
We use data to infer information about the population or process in order to obtain such evidence; if the data are sufficiently inconsistent with the explanation/model (in a particular sense), we are led to reject the null.
In particular under the N-P approach we identify a rejection rule based on a summary of the data set (a test statistic) that should tend to produce different behavior when the alternative hypothesis is true, from when the null is true and we want the test statistics that would most strongly indicate the alternative to produce rejections of the null.
Creating a rejection rule involves probability calculations. In particular we seek to avoid rejecting true nulls very often, and set a threshold for that which we wish to avoid exceeding.
Those probability calculations rely on randomness. Typically that randomness either comes from obtaining the data via some form of random sampling from a population or process, or (in experiments) by randomizing given subjects to treatments. Given we don't seem to be dealing with an experiment here, I'll leave that option aside -- we rely in some sense on the sample being randomly chosen from a set of possible samples, and that randomness then allows the use of probability models in relation to inference about an incompletely observed target population.
In order for the probability calculations to be meaningful we directly rely on this randomness.
As a result, we should be clear about what our target population or process is - i.e. the thing about which we are trying to make statements in our hypotheses, and the sense in which the data we are going to gather can reasonably be treated as being obtained from it randomly. The details of that sense in which we have a random sample impacts the calculations, and the extent to which the conclusions would be meaningful.

... to determine if there is a significant difference between these stories in terms of the word count and then another test to determine if there is a significant difference between the stories in terms of the number of plurals.

The first issue is that you have four specific stories; if you are comparing just those stories, there's nothing to infer. I think Ben covers that issue in some detail, so I refer you to that answer.
If the stories were instead selected from some set of underlying categories at random then there might be some argument for trying to infer something about the typical story length in such categories. We presently have no evidence for this.  (If it was the case the first question is why you'd only select one.)
I will continue, however, and assume for the present you were able to marshal some such argument. Without it or something very like it, what follows would not be meaningful.
Given that assumption, it's not at all clear that there's any sense in which the length of a story would reasonably be regarded as a random value from some count process (such as a Poisson process, say). It seems to me that selecting stories from within some category of story types, it's more like selecting a duration from a set of durations. A story has structure and is as long as it takes to tell the story; it doesn't just end at random. In any case, some model for story-length within category would have to be selected to make progress.
The second issue - that of comparing tendency to produce plurals - may have a little more potential.
If we were able to regard the occurrence of plurals vs non-plurals as some kind of random process within a story, then there might be some sense in which comparison between specific stories might be made. For example, if it made sense to treat each word being plural or not as occurring independently and with constant probability, there would then be a basis to compare proportions (/rates  -- not counts, but counts per unit length). I don't think there's a good basis for such an assumption on several grounds, but there's perhaps more opportunity with a somewhat more complicated model. I don't claim this makes sense in your context, only that it has some potential for making such an argument. (I will not be making that argument for you, it would require intimate knowledge of the subject area, for starters, expertise I don't possess.)
Clearly the stories you mention don't have identical length, but let me make the example more stark: imagine you were comparing a sonnet to Hamlet.
A sonnet has about 100 words, give or take, so the total count of plurals much be considerably shorter. Hamlet has about 4000 lines and many thousands of words. To compare the counts of plurals would make no sense; obviously Hamlet will have hundreds of times more plurals, even if some characteristic of it meant that it had a considerably lower rate of plurals in it.
Such a stylistic difference would show up as a change in the proportion or rate of occurrence of plurals.
So, if you were able to make arguments to overcome a number of hurdles relating to whether it even makes sense at all to invoke some model of randomness, then given known story length, it might be conceivable to try to build some model of occurrence of plurals and then test a hypothesis relating to how plural-dense each story was.
There's not enough detail in the question to even guess at whether there might be a possibility to make such arguments. I strongly doubt it, but don't rule it out altogether.

Regarding the rationale of running a test here, I think one can justify this to some extent from the background (as explained in a comment):

The purpose of the test is to ensure that these stories are not significantly different in terms of their difficulty of reading. It is for a psychology study where we need to ensure that there is no confound in the story difficulty.

The logic that is apparently applied here is that if a number of measurable  characteristics of the texts are very similar (one of which is the relative number of plurals), the texts can be seen as similarly difficult. In fact, optimally, the questioner would want to make a case that they have the same difficulty, but this can of course never be nailed down precisely.
I am not a linguist, and I can't comment on to what extent relative frequency of plurals is related to difficulty. Let's assume the questioner is right that it is.
The idea is then that texts are deemed similar enough (on this criterion) if the data are compatible with having drawn the words of all four texts randomly from the same process. Obviously this is not how things have been in reality (words in texts are not independent to begin with), but I'd say that as a calibration device this is a somewhat useful fiction, i.e., just for the sake of having an objective (i.e., observable and reproducible) definition of what "so similar that the underlying difficulty level might just be the same" actually means. At least I have a hard time to imagine a better criterion unless one can make a specific linguistic justification of some other numerical rule.
The problem I see with this is that a statistical test may reject the null hypothesis of same distribution/mean/probability for large enough samples even if the deviation from the null hypothesis is very small, meaning that it may be hard (for texts that are long enough) to find any four texts (fulfilling further side conditions potentially relevant in this study, like being "long enough", whatever that means here) where one would not reject the null hypothesis here (or in other tests regarding other criteria). Texts may really not be essentially different in difficulty where relative plural occurrences deviate a bit from a random null model, even if the latter is rejected.
This is not a problem as long as the researchers are able to put together a set of such stories where the tests do not reject, but if such a set of stories can't be found, chances are they need to change the logic (particularly here, dependence between words that can generally not be avoided may be enough to explain rejection).
It is important to acknowledge that the criterion "don't reject by such a statistical test" for accepting a set of stories is somewhat artificial and not based on such probability models being "true" or even approximately realistic. As a formal calibration device without ambition of model realism I think it can be defended. It can for sure be argued why not rejecting is a good thing given the aim of the researchers, but the issue whether a set of of stories may be acceptable anyway where one or more of their tests reject (depending on which test and how strong the rejection) is far more thorny.
By the way, if this logic is accepted, I can well imagine that a simple chi squared test with plural vs. non-plural over the four stories will do. Nothing wrong with the Poisson model proposed elsewhere though (I wonder whether these are even equivalent but haven't thought that through).
